# debuging--Class / object stuff, noob problems

Tags: c++, object

Please tear this code apart, make it complex and scarcely readable, I'd rather learn the hard way once than learn the same thing many times the wrong way.

The base class is as follows:

```
class baseMob{
private:
    int _healthMax;
    int _healthCurrent;
    int _manaMax;
    int _manaCurrent;
    int _experiencePoints;
public:
    //Set max Hp
    void setHealthMax(int);
    //Get max Hp
    int getHealthMax();
    //Set Current Hp
    void setCurrentHealth(int);
    //Get Current Health
    int getCurrentHealth();
    //Set Max Mana
    void setMaxMana(int);
    //Get Max Mana
    int getMaxMana();
    //Set Current Mana
    void setCurrentMana(int);
    //Get Current Mana 
    int getCurrentMana();
    //getMob Exp on kill
    int getExperiencePoints();
    //Set mob Exp points
    void setExperiencePoints(int);
//leaving out the member functions for space conservation

};
```

The individual mob that I'm trying to create is a green slime, which I'm trying to create via the default constructor I've made...

```
   class greenSlime: private baseMob{
    public:
        greenSlime(){
            setHealthMax(100);
            setMaxMana(100);
            setCurrentHealth(100);
            setCurrentMana(100);
            setExperiencePoints(150);
        }
    };
```

My main function looks like this right now:

```
 greenSlime slime();
    for(; slime.getCurrentHealth() >= 0; slime.setCurrentHealth(-1)){
        cout << "The current health of the slime is: " << slime.getCurrentHealth() << endl;
        if (slime.getCurrentHealth() <= 0 ){
            cout << "Player is awarded with: " << slime.getExperiencePoints() << " Experience. ";
        }
    }
```

If anyone wants to tear this up and make me look like a jackass, I'd really appreciate the help.

The error that I'm presently getting is:

Project1.cpp:107: error: request for member `getCurrentHealth' in`slime', which is of non-class type `greenSlime ()()'

Along with other errors of the same type.

Tl;Dr:  Class implementation isn't working, posted all my source when I probably could've posted about 1/10th of this and still made sense, and would love to have someone tell me why it's not working and how bad I am.

Comment: I think one of the main problems is all the self-deprecation in your question.  You're a learner - *that's ok*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate.  Amusingly enough I figured out the base problem that I was looking for.  Also:  My question history on SO has been...sordid at best, I've been told I have crap syntax / style a number of times.

Comment: "Sordid" is a pretty extreme description.  If we're curt, it's because life is short.

Comment: @Nate "If I'm curt, then I apologize. But I was told time is a factor."

Comment: @HansPassant Right now my goal is to simply create a greenSlime object named slime that have it's 'health' reduced to 0 and then award the 'player' with experience.   My code may / may not have been updated since you wrote that comment too.

Comment: Also: since you're constructing *slime on the heap now, don't forget to end your main function with `delete slime`

Comment: Hmya, you invalidated Tom's answer as well.  That's not okay, rolled back.

Comment: @djacobson So, pretty please... with sugar on top. Write better f*ing code?

Comment: @Nate Upon reflection, I *have* worked on codebases that resemble the interior of a car in which someone has been shot in the face...

Comment: @HansPassant In fairness the code revision came before both your and Tom's comment / answer was posted.  I'm not entirely sure what SO rules are, but I'm pretty sure I'm allowed to revamp my own question before there are any answers, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out problems in terms of why your code doesn't work. I'll make a recommendation about program design.

When explaining inheritance, tutorials and programming classes frequently use toy examples that are very similar to your code. These examples show what inheritance is, but really aren't very good at showing what inheritance is useful for.

I wouldn't use inheritance in this case. I think a better design is to have a class that represents the mob type and holds all the data that is static for all that mob of that type, such as the mob name, starting/max HP, attack types, etc. And then have another class where each instance represents a specific mob and holds data that changes for that mob, such as current hp.

```
class Mob_type {
    string name;
    int max_hp;
    vector<shared_ptr<Attack_type>> attacks;
public:
    Mob_type(string name,int max_hp,vector<shared_ptr<Attack_type>> attacks)
    : name(name),max_hp(max_hp),attacks(attacks) {}
    int get_max_hp() const { return max_hp; }
};

class Mob {
    Mob_type const &type;
    int hp;
public:
    Mob(Mob_type const &type) : type(type), hp(type.get_max_hp()) {}
    Mob_type const &get_type() const { return type; }
    int get_hp() const { return hp; }
};

void print_health(Mob const &m) {
    cout << m.get_hp() << '/' << m.get_type().get_max_hp() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    vector<shared_ptr<Attack_type>> attacks; // ...
    Mob_type green_slime("Green Slime",50,attacks);

    Mob green_slime_A(green_slime), green_slime_B(green_slime);

    fight(green_slime_A,green_slime_B);

    cout << "A: ";
    print_health(green_slime_A);
    cout << "B: ";
    print_health(green_slime_B);

}
```

This way you can have a data file that contains the mob types and all you have to do to add a type is to update the data file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the compiler thinks that the slime declaration line is another type of predeclaration since greenSlime doesn't have a ctor with parameters.

You can fix it by not putting the parenthesis after slime.

```
// greenSlime slime();
greenSlime slime;
```

Here is the absolute best advice I can give regarding weird errors that you don't understand.  Make a smaller example of the problem makes it easier to uncover what is actually wrong.

Here is what I wrote to test.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved it while you were typing this!!  This will be a big help for future reference though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class greenSlime: private baseMob{
```

should be:

```
class greenSlime: public baseMob{
```

Since the class that you're inheriting from is **private**, you can't see any of the inherited methods.

Also, what Tom Kerr said, you don't want the parentheses after you declare your object.  Basically, if you don't want any parameters, don't use the parentheses when making an object.

Answer (score 1):

Also, very next thing I imagine you'll encounter: you almost never want [private inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html), at least not unless you *know* you really want it. I'm guessing you meant for the class declaration of greenSlime to be 
`class greenSlime: public baseMob`

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you make private inheritance you won't be able to access any of base class' functions. Public inheritance allows you access base class' public and protected functions and members.

Second if you want to make a pointer of greenSlime class, you must do:

```
//greenSlime() with parentheses
greenSlime *slime = new greenSlime();
```

But if you want to make an object of greenSlime with non parameter constructor (default constructor) you must do:

```
//without parentheses
greenSlime slime;
```